# Plotting a dataframe as many line-graphs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe such as:

```
   x   y   z
   1   1   100
   1   2   150
   1   3   200
   2   1   125
   2   2   175
   2   3   225
   3   1   225
   3   2   275
   3   3   325
   ...
```

I want to plot, on the same graph, $z$ as a function of $y$, for each value of $x$. So that there will be a plot for $x=1$, a plot for $x=2$, a plot for $x=3$, etc.

I tried this:

```
ax = df[df['x']==1].plot(x='y',y='x', title='x==1')
df[df['x']==2].plot(x='y',y='x', title='x==2', ax=ax)
df[df['x']==3].plot(x='y',y='x', title='x==3', ax=ax)
```

This indeed makes the 3 correct plots, but, they are all called the same on the legend, so I cannot tell which line-plot belongs to which value of $x$.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

***(option I):*** Iterate through sub-groups of the grouped object and plot on the same axes, `ax`:

```
ax = plt.gca()                     # get current axes to plot against
for num, g in df.groupby('x'):
    g.plot(x='y', y='z', ax=ax, label="x=={}".format(num))
# plt.ylabel("z")                  # to display y-axis label
plt.show()
```

---

***(option II):*** Set *y* and *x* as the index axis in the same order. Unstack so that *x* becomes the column. Modify the column names by using `add_prefix` so that the legends get formatted this way. Set the name attribute of the columns as `None` and finally plot.

```
df.set_index(['y', 'x'])['z'].unstack().add_prefix("x==").rename_axis(None, axis=1).plot()
```

---

Both create the following plot:

### [image]

***Data used:***

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=np.repeat([1,2,3], 3),
                       y=np.tile([1,2,3], 3),
                       z=np.random.randint(100,500,9)))
df
```

[image]